# dmenu alternative that supports input streaming

Tags: streaming

I have a list of 1.8k songs in `audacious` and it took a while for the `audtool` to retrieve this list, as such
`audtool --playlist-display | dmenu` will be delayed for about 1 second before the dmenu appears. Is there an alternative for dmenu that enable streaming? i.e. it doesn't wait for the input stream to be finished but appears immediately and prompts for user input.

fzf ([link](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)) is a good alternative that supports streaming but it is only for command line, I am looking for a gui tool like dmenu.

Answer (score 0):

Since `fzf` can act as a standard unix filter on texts, it would be possible to use `fzf` on top of `dmenu` to update its output.